# Scrape lat and lon from mapbox

Tags: python, mapbox

I would like to use Python to scrape the lat and lon of all the items on this mapbox map but I cannot seem to find the right query.

I have tried this but it doesnt seem to get me anywhere, any help would be appreciated:

```
import requests
import bs4
import json


url = 'https://www.bakerinstitute.org/sites/default/files/2023-04/China_Energy_Map_040323.html'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}


response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```